# Is it possible to make cross browser website without having any IE conditional CSS?

Tags: css, xhtml, cross-browser

If i I'm not using any transparent png, not using :hover on other thank a:link,

Is it possible to make cross browser layout without having any IE conditional CSS .and keep main css valid?

I want to keep only one css file for whole needs. screen, print, handheld.

What things we should consider?

Comment: "No news is good news" = "No css is valid css". Just use the tags that are supported by IE as well as other browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.  The main thing I do to work on this is to test the CSS files incrementally in multiple browsers as I build the site.  It's much harder to make a site look correct in multiple browsers once it is completely built out for a single browser.

Element widths are the biggest problem since different browsers calculate the widths differently.

Comment: how to deal with elements width for cross browser compatibility

Comment: If you're using a strict doctype widths of elements shouldn't be trouble (especially IE7+)

Comment: @Ryan Doherty - I'm using XHTML 1.1

Comment: @metal-gear-solid - Then you don't need to worry about both IE and validity. You can't validly serve XHTML 1.1 as text/html and you can't get IE to render the page if you don't serve your page as text/html.

Comment: @Alohci - "You can't validly serve XHTML 1.1 as text/html" why?

Comment: @metal-gear-solid - It's not permitted by the XHTML 1.1 spec. It takes a stricter line to serving it using an XML mime type than XHTML 1.0 did. There have been proposals to change this, but many people are opposed to it, so no such proposal has made it to W3C recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just use one column.

For more complicated designs, I guess it depends on the design and the exact browser requirements.